# chruby installations failing

Tags: ruby, chruby

I am attempting to get ruby set up to work on an older project and running into an issue where I can not seem to get chruby to successfully install ruby 2.2.0 which I need for some of the packages in the existing project (ruby_dep-1.5.0).

I am working on a new Macbook Pro, M2 Chip, Ventura 13.2.1 and chruby install works fine up until this point:

```
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
making enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `enc'.
making srcs under enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
generating transdb.h
transdb.h unchanged
making trans
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `./enc/trans'.
making encs
generating makefile exts.mk
Failed to configure -test-/win32/console. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure -test-/win32/dln. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure -test-/win32/dln/empty. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure -test-/win32/fd_setsize. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure fiddle. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure gdbm. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure openssl. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure readline. It will not be installed.
configuring socket
Failed to configure syslog. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure tk. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure tk/tkutil. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure win32. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure win32ole. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure zlib. It will not be installed.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing default bigdecimal libraries
installing default date_core libraries
installing digest libraries
installing default digest libraries
installing default sha2 libraries
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing default console libraries
installing default libraries
installing default nkf libraries
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing default pathname libraries
installing default psych libraries
installing default pty libraries
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
installing default ripper libraries
checking ../.././parse.y and ../.././ext/ripper/eventids2.c
linking shared-object socket.bundle
installing default socket libraries
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: `ruby' is up to date.
Generating RDoc documentation

No newer files.

  Files:      0

  Classes:    0 (0 undocumented)
  Modules:    0 (0 undocumented)
  Constants:  0 (0 undocumented)
  Attributes: 0 (0 undocumented)
  Methods:    0 (0 undocumented)

  Total:      0 (0 undocumented)
    0.00% documented

  Elapsed: 0.0s

config.status: creating -darwin22-fake.rb
rm: illegal option -- a
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dIPRrvWx] file ...
       unlink [--] file
config.status: error: could not create -darwin22-fake.rb
make: *** [-darwin22-fake.rb] Error 64
!!! Installation of ruby 2.2.0 failed!
```

Thoughts?  Thanks for any and all help you can share.